# ReactJS Ref: undefined error getting input element value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code I am setting up a `ref` on the `<input/>` element which is used during the `<form>` element's `onSubmit` handler.

For some reason I am getting the following error when submitting the form:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

How can I prevent this error?

```
import React from "react";

class AddItemForm extends React.Component {

  nameRef = React.createRef();

  createItem = event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const item = {
      name: this.nameRef.value.value,      
    };  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="item-edit" onSubmit={this.createItem}>
        <input name="name" ref={this.nameRef} type="text" placeholder="Name" />        
        <button type="submit">+ Add Item</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default AddItemForm;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the first `value` with `current` seeing that the ref object provides access to the underlying DOM element via that field.

The following should resolve your problem:

```
createItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const item = {
       name: this.nameRef.current.value,      // Replace value with current 
    };
    console.log(item);      
}
```